ehcache startup parameter usage
We are using liferay portal and using wildfly to deploy it. We are using following property in startup parameter. What following startup parameter will do?
-Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true

I've never seen that mentioned with Liferay anywhere. Why are you using this in the first place? Also, please see [help/on-topic]: This question is not related to a programming problem, but about running 3rd party software.
